# How to update subscription memo field with stripe api?

Tags: stripe-payments

there is the memo field that stripe allows to edit on dashboard

and it's said that `This will appear on any invoices and receipts`.

That's exactly what I need - field that is inherited by invoices and viewed in invoice emails

Though there is no memo field on subscription object that api returns https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object

Where is it?

Comment: This does not exist in Stripe's API. You should talk to their support team: https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: I have contacted stripe support, they have promised to add memo field to api

Comment: @srghma Any updates ?

Comment: @GeneVincent no, I wasn't notified about this feature being added, you can ask that support team too. Please write about if this feature is added.

Comment: Update from October 2019... Support team just told me "Not available, we'll send the team a feature request". They don't seem to be putting much effort into it if they gave you the same answer a year ago

Answer (score 0):

There is somewhat of an incomplete work-around, if anyone is still looking for a solution.  Stripe will create a draft invoice an hour or so before finalizing and collecting payment.  If you register a webhook for the invoice.created event, you can use it to grab the invoice object and update the memo field.  The very 1st invoice however (when the subscription is created), is finalized immediately; before the webhook is called.  And once it is finalized, you cannot update it.  So the technique works for all but the first invoice sent out.

It is, of course, not a great solution.  Besides the 1st invoice problem it is complex; relying on a webhook for the update is problematic.

Sucks, I know, but it's the only thing I could come up with.